# VPN Multi site routing

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking, ipsec

I am currently setting up a multi site (3 sites) VPN.

Here is a quick drawing:

[image]

So far the setup is fine and working as expected. Pinging 10.10.20.1 <-> 10.10.10.1 as well as 10.10.30.1 <-> 10.10.10.1 is working fine.

**Now I want to figure out how to connect from 10.10.20.1 to 10.10.30.1.**

I think I need to use `iptables` to do this, is that correct?

If someone can explain what steps are necessary and why would help me a lot!

Comment: Since both the .20 and .30 sites have IPSec capability, why not just build tunnels between the two of them, also?

Comment: That is not what I want. I want to learn how things work

Comment: Firstly, SF is a site for professional sysadmins, not a learning resource for beginners. Secondly, the mesh topology is the right way to use IPSec, because otherwise NAT is unavoidable, and as others have said, that's not a great idea.

Comment: Why is everybody complaining about NAT? I don't want to use NAT at all (hence I deleted the part from my initial question). I just pointed that out to give you an idea what method I've tried.

SF IS a learning resource like all other 'stacks' are q.e.d.

Comment: With respect, you may find that marching into a particular forum and telling people what it's for doesn't get you the best possible response.

Comment: hence my respond to you telling people what its for ;-). Anyways - no one seemed to understand my question, and no one asked for more details. I figured it out by myself and let everyone benefit from it by posting a detailed answer. Not only was there no up vote but also a down vote. at least there are three people involved doing something.

Comment: @MadHatter It's possible to route traffic through multiple IPSec tunnels without any NAT being used. But I still agree that a full mesh is the way to go for performance reasons.

Comment: @tuna NAT is complicated and will cause things to break. It should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: There is not even a single „NAT“ in my question :D. I did solve my question by my own as you can see.

Comment: @tuna I think what happened here is that when you mentioned `iptables` we assumed you wanted to use the NAT functionality in `iptables` instead of setting up proper routing tables. There is absolutely nothing wrong with setting up VPNs and in addition to that filter traffic with `iptables` as appropriate.

Comment: @tuna You still haven't explained why you haven't set up a full mesh of VPN tunnels. As long as you don't have a large number of sites, the full mesh of VPN tunnels will give you the best performance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my long and quick solution:

### long (not quite) solution

On the bottom server:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.30.0/24 -d 10.10.20.0/24 -i enp2s0 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec --reqid 2 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.20.0/24 -d 10.10.30.0/24 -o enp2s0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec --reqid 2 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.20.0/24 -d 10.10.30.0/24 -i enp2s0 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec --reqid 1 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.30.0/24 -d 10.10.20.0/24 -o enp2s0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec --reqid 1 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
```

On the top left server:

```
ip route add 10.10.30.0/24 via 138.x.x.1 dev eth0 proto static src 10.10.20.1 table 220
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.30.0/24 -d 10.10.20.0/24 -i eth0 -m . policy --dir in --pol ipsec --reqid 2 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.20.0/24 -d 10.10.30.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec --reqid 2 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
```

On the top right server:

```
ip route add 10.10.20.0/24 via 108.x.x.1 dev eth0 proto static src 10.10.30.1 table 220
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.20.0/24 -d 10.10.30.0/24 -i eth0 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec --reqid 2 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.10.30.0/24 -d 10.10.20.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec --reqid 2 --proto esp -j ACCEPT
```

Though it does work routing wise strongswan is prohibiting connections as a tcpdump revealed.

```
[bottom]$ tcpdump -nni enp2s0 icmp
15:35:22.512437 IP 109.x.x.x > 85.x.x.x: ICMP host 109.x.x.x unreachable - admin prohibited, length 48
```

### quick solution

This solution is pretty neat because strongswan/ipsec is managing all the iptable and static routes for you and also allowing access to the specified subnets.

On the bottom server:

```
# /etc/ipsec.conf
conn top-left-to-bottom
    ...
    leftsubnet=10.10.10.0/24,10.10.30.0/24
    ...

conn top-right-to-bottom
    ...
    leftsubnet=10.10.10.0/24,10.10.20.0/24
    ...
```

On the top left server:

```
# /etc/ipsec.conf
conn top-left-to-bottom
    ...
    rightsubnet=10.10.10.0/24,10.10.30.0/24
    ...
```

On the top right server:

```
# /etc/ipsec.conf
conn top-right-to-bottom
    ...
    rightsubnet=10.10.10.0/24,10.10.20.0/24
    ...
```

Here is how a successful tcpdumped ping should look like:

```
[bottom]$ tcpdump -nni enp2s0 icmp
15:52:37.160859 IP 10.10.20.1 > 10.10.30.1: ICMP echo request, id 1296, seq 1, length 64
15:52:37.164971 IP 10.10.30.1 > 10.10.20.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1296, seq 1, length 64
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't NAT. NAT is a kludge that is to be avoided whereever possible. It breaks the end-to-end principle used as a foundation of TCP/IP.

With static routes you need to point them into the tunnel. If the routers exchange routing information (OSPF, ...) the routes should be coming up automatically. To get the tunnels up, static routes may be required (dynamic routing only updates once the tunnel is up).

Comment: If I add `ip route add 10.10.30.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.20.1` to the top left server I am not able to reach the top right server (I also have done this to the top right server `ip route add 10.10.20.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.30.1`.

I am also running tcpdump on the bottom server while pinging. I am not receiving anything there. That of course means that the route I've added does not work.

Comment: You'll need IP forwarding enabled on the middle host

Comment: @JacobEvans that must already be on, as it's already routing between .10 and each of the other two networks.